# Let A be a nonsingular square matrix with integer entries. Prove that inverse of A contains only integer entries if and only if det(A) = ±1.

Tags: linear-algebra

How can we describe the enteries of a matrix by just knowing the determinant of it?

Comment: Do you know Cramer's rule?

Comment: If you know what a cofactor and adjoint (or sometimes called, adjugate) is, then you can see that all the cofactors are integers (since they are products and sums of integers). Hence, the adjoint of a matrix with integer entries has integer entries. Now, the inverse is $A^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{\det A} \text{adj } A$. Since scalar multiplication works on every element, it is very easy to see that, in general, the entries will remain integer iff $\det A = \pm 1$.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh That only proves $A^{-1}$ has integer entries if $|\det A|=1$ for a matrix $A$ with integer entries.

Comment: It also proves that, in general, if $\det A \neq \pm 1$, then $A^{-1}$ does not have integer entries. That is what I have written.